# Recursive divide and conquer approach to maximum continuous sum on a circular array

Tags: arrays, circular-buffer

I'm implementing a divide and conquer approach to solve the maximum sum problem recursively. I've gotten it down for a regular array but I'm struggling to implement it for a circular array.

Right now, I'm trying to use modulus to just go over the array twice basically. But it's not giving me the correct results and I'm unsure why.

Here is my code so far:

Recursive Call:

```
    private static int maxSubarray(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
    //base case
    if(high == low) {
        return(arr[low % arr.length]);
    } else {
        int mid = (low + high)/2;

        return Math.max(Math.max(maxSubarray(arr, low, mid), 
                maxSubarray(arr, mid+1, high)), maxCrossing(arr, low, mid, high));
    }
}
```

Crossing Call:

```
    private static int maxCrossing(int[] arr, int low, int mid, int high) {
    int leftSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = mid % arr.length; i >= low % arr.length; i--) {
        sum += arr[i];
        if(sum > leftSum) {
            leftSum = sum;
        }
    }
    int rightSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
    sum = 0;
    for(int j = (mid + 1) % arr.length; j <= high % arr.length; j++) {
        sum += arr[j];
        if(sum > rightSum) {
            rightSum = sum;
        }
    }
    return(leftSum + rightSum);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Anything in the above code that has "% arr.length" deviates from the non-circular array implementation.

Also, I am not looking to implement Kadane's method.

EDIT:

Forgot to mention my initial call would be maxSubarray(arr, 0, arr.length * 2 - 1) - basically going over the elements twice.

EDIT2:

Figured out something here. As this is an assignment, I'll wait until after the due date to post my working solution.

Comment: If you have it working in a non-circular array of length n, then you're almost done. Just run the non-circular version on an array of length 2n that contains two consecutive copies of the original input.  Then think it through. You don't really need to make the 2n-long array. You need only to "fool" the algorithm into thinking its running on that array by adding index arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks for replying to me! I think right now I'm stuck on the fact that it will go over elements more than once (i.e - adding arr[0] twice by reading the array 2n times and getting an inaccurate sum. Do you think I should perhaps implement another helper method to read the array from midpoint to midpoint ( arr[length/2] to arr[length/2 - 1] ) and then compare the sum to the method that reads from arr[0] to arr[length]? Or am I making this more complicated than it needs to be?